# My code for iOS App Emailing does not work with dynamic values

Tags: ios, objective-c, email, ios7

i am trying to set up a share your score email in my "game" and i have a value called totalCircles1 which should be an integer, this is the import code for the file:

```
#import "ShareViewController.h"
#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>
#import "CircleTableViewController.h"
```

And this is the code i am using to send the email:

```
    - (IBAction)emailShareButton:(id)sender {

    self.emailSenderVC = [MFMailComposeViewController new];
    self.emailSenderVC.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    NSString *body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hey, I just got a score of %d in the Circle Creator iPhone App! \n Check it out at: www.circlecreator.com ! ", totalCircles1];
    [self.emailSenderVC setMessageBody:body isHTML:NO];
    [self.emailSenderVC setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-------@gmail.com", nil]];

    [self presentViewController:self.emailSenderVC animated:YES completion:nil];


}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
    switch (result) {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            break;

        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Message sent" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
            break;
        }

        default:
            break;
    }

    [self.emailSenderVC dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

And when i do this i get an error next to the quote ", totalCircles1];" saying use of undeclared identifier "Total Circles 1"

And i implement it more or less here:

```
for(int i=1; i<=9; i++) {
    if((indexPath.row * 9  + i) <= totalCircles1) {
        NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d@%d", i, indexPath.row];

        if([self.cache objectForKey:key]) {
```

This is the code that works but it is the view controller where the value is created:

```
 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
totalCircles1 = [[defaults objectForKey:@"Total Circles"] intValue];

self.totalCirlesLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Total circles: %d", totalCircles1];
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: Where and how do you declare `totalCircles1`?

Comment: Not 100% sure but I'm able to use it here:  NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    totalCircles1 = [[defaults objectForKey:@"Total Circles"] intValue];

    self.totalCirlesLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Total circles: %d", totalCircles1];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

Comment: Answering this question is going to be a long, hard, slog...

Comment: Try NSLog(@"Number= %d", totalCircles1) also please show where you create totalCircles1… i.e. somewhere you will have something like: int totalCircles1;

Comment: @CoconidoHD: ok, so it is a property of _something_. Can you check in what class this property is defined? If it is in the same class as your `emailShareButton:` method is defined then a simple change of `totalCircles1` to `self. totalCircles1` will do. Otherwise you will need a reference to the object that holds it.

Comment: It is definitely defined in a different class...]

Comment: Then you need a reference to the object that holds it and use  `objectreference.totalCircles1`. If you use merely `totalCircles1` compiler will expect a local method variable or an ivar of the object where method is in.

Comment: Do i have to replace "objectreference" with anything?

Comment: Sorry I'm kind of just starting out :/

Comment: You should pass as @rokjarc said, a reference to your object that has the totalcircles property, to the object you need to access that info in.

Comment: @CoconidoHD when you alloc init the object with the "emailShareButton" code, you need to also pass in a reference to the object with the total circles property, or the property value itself.

Comment: @CoconidoHD: don't worry, everybody was starting out at some point ;) Yes, `objectreference` is just an example that should be replaced with a reference to an object that is holding the property `totalCircles1`. I know - i suck at explaining things.

Comment: But how do i find "a reference to an object that is holding the property totalCircles1"

Comment: I'm trying to think of a good tutorial for this case. It is hard to explain in just a couple of sentences.

Comment: maybe just tell me in the comment what i should type but don't worry if you can't :)

Comment: I'd have to see more code to be able to do that.

Comment: What parts would you need to see?

Comment: probably appDelegate, ShareViewController and CircleTableViewController

Comment: If you don't mind i could email them to you :/

Comment: But don't worry thank you so much for your help mate :)

Answer (score 0):

where do you define `totalCircles1`? If you have it as a @property you need to access it with self.totalCircles1

Based on the comments try this:

```
- (IBAction)emailShareButton:(id)sender {

// add these 2 lines to your code 
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
int totalCircles1 = [[defaults objectForKey:@"Total Circles"] intValue];


self.emailSenderVC = [MFMailComposeViewController new];
self.emailSenderVC.mailComposeDelegate = self;

NSString *body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hey, I just got a score of %d in the Circle Creator iPhone App! \n Check it out at: www.circlecreator.com ! ", totalCircles1];
[self.emailSenderVC setMessageBody:body isHTML:NO];
[self.emailSenderVC setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-------@gmail.com", nil]];

[self presentViewController:self.emailSenderVC animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: This is a comment and not an answer.

Comment: kinda both, "If you have it as a @property you need to access it with self.totalCircles1" is an answer

Comment: Yes i think it might be an @property, if you look at the comment i made above the code like that works, but in a different view controller

Comment: Just because it is a property doesn't mean you have to access it via the property. You can use the ivar directly.

Comment: How can i access a property that is defined in a different class

Comment: I updated the question based on these comments and the ones above, hope it helps.